# show how equation (1) is re-expressed as equation (2)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

[image: problem im stuck on]

Im really stuck on this problem, its for an applied mathematical modelling class. I spoke to my professor about it and he said to really have a think about it, as if its a trick question or has a trivial answer.

the question asks to: show and explain how eq (1) is re expressed as eq (2)

Im thinking something along the lines of: $$dS=S_{t+Δt}-S_t$$ and $$dt=Δt$$
because dS represents a change in S ($S_{t+Δt}-S_t$ is a change in S) and dt represents a change in t (Δt is a change in t)
so $$\frac{S_{t+Δt}-S_t}{dt} = F_{s,in} - F_{s,out}$$
$$\frac{S_{t+Δt}}{dt} = S_t + (F_{s,in} - F_{s,out})$$
$$S_{t+Δt} = S_t + (F_{s,in} - F_{s,out})*Δt$$

even if this arithmetic is correct, I still dont know how to explain it. I could just be over thinking it.

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the point, we just need to remember a bit of theory from calculus 1,
$$
\frac{dS}{dt} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{S(t + \Delta t) - S(t)}{ \Delta t}
$$
Here we're using $S(t) = S_t$ and $S(t + \Delta t) = S_{t + \Delta t}$. So as $\Delta t \to 0$, the two formula are identical.

In theory, we can measure increments that are arbitrarily close in time ($ \Delta t \to 0$). In practice, this absolutely never happens and you pay \$\$\$ for each decimal place of precision. The underlying process (fluid flux) is continuous and smooth, so our limit should converge if we could only take a finer time step.

If you assume your phenomena is smooth, you could consider the Taylor series expansion and use a series representation to estimate the order of accuracy (big O notation) convergence of the approximation, but you've got the idea for a modeling class.

Comment: oh the definition of the derivative! i cant believe i didnt think of that! thankyou for your response, it has been very helpful.